# Graph Theory-Breadth First Search

Tags: graph-theory

I've been asked the following:

Show that the length of the shortest path from $u$ to $v$ in a connected graph $G$ equals the level of $v$ in *any* BFS tree of $G$ rooted at $u$.

I can't find any proof of this. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'Show' it. That may be a lesser requirement than a formal proof.
Certainly for only 3 points on your exam.

Then it is probably sufficient to tell that you will at least need a tree of depth $L$, but you also don't need more than $L$. Where $L$ is the length of the shortest path.

You just rearrange the vertices at level $l$ in $1..L$ as the distance from $u$.

(Look for Dijkstra's algorithm)